# Higher Moments of Sums of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1 \dots X_n$ be independent random variables taking values $\{-1,1\}$ with equal probability 1/2. Let $S_n = \sum X_i$. Is there a closed form expression for $E[(S_n)^{2j}]$. If not a closed form expression then can we hope to get a nice tight upper bound. I am leaving tight unspecified here because I do not know myself how tight I want the bound to be so please tell me any non-trivial bounds.

Comment: Which asymptotics? $n$ fixed and $j\to\infty$ or $j$ fixed and $n\to\infty$?

Comment: n fixed j going to infinity

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $S_n^{2j}$ takes the value $(2k-n)^{2j}$ with probability $\binom nk\frac 1{2^n}$, hence 
$$\mathbb E\left[S_n^{2j}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(2k-n)^{2j}.$$
It involves computations of terms of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk k^p$, $p\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Right but I am sorry, I still cant see a closed form or a good bound.

Answer (score 1):

For every fixed $n\geqslant1$,  $|S_n|\leqslant n$ almost surely, $P[|S_n|=n]=2^{1-n}$ and if $|S_n|\ne n$ then $|S_n|\leqslant n-1$, hence 
$$
\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}n^{-2j}\cdot E[(S_n)^{2j}]=P[|S_n|=n]=2^{1-n}.
$$
To prove this (or if nonasymptotic bounds are needed), use the inequalities
$$
P[|S_n|=n]\cdot n^{2j}\leqslant E[(S_n)^{2j}]\leqslant P[|S_n|=n]\cdot n^{2j}+(n-1)^{2j}.
$$